# How do i implement these methods from a class into a main class?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have these 4 methods that are in a separate class. I need to test them in a main class. How do i implement them in the main class?

```
 public void dodeliZival (Zival zival) {
    for (int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
        if(zivali[i] == null) {
            zivali[i]=zival;
            break;
        }
    }   }

           public void odvzamiZival(Zival zival) {
            for(int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
                if(zivali[i] == zival) {
                    zivali[i]=null;
                break;
                }
            }}

         public int vrniSteviloZivali() {
          int st = 0;
          for(int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
            if(zivali[i] != null)
                    st++;
                }
                return st;
            }
           public boolean zivalObstaja(String ime) {
        for(int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
            if(zivali[i].ime.equals(ime)) {
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The methods are inside a class. In the main you use that class, delcare the arguments for each method with the values you want to test, and then call the methods on the object passing the corresponding argument and finally you check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement interfaces not classes.
You must create an instance to run this methods.

```
ClassName c = new ClassName();
c.exampleMethod();
```

In Java, you can create an instance with 'new' keyword.

Comment: If you are going to add this as an answer instead of a comment, at least write a complete anwer explaining each step.